# What are Mutual_info_regression and Mutual_info_classif used for?

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, deep-learning

I'm learning about feature selection of big datasets. I came across a method called "Mutual_info_regression" and "Mutual_info_classif". It returns a value for all the features. What that value represents ??

Answer (score 3):

They both measure the [mutual information](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mutual_information) between a matrix containing a set of feature vectors and the target. They are under [`sklearn.feature_selection`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/classes.html#module-sklearn.feature_selection), since the mutual information can be used to gain some understanding on how good of a predictor a feature may be. This is a core concept in information theory, which is closely linked to that of [entropy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entropy_(information_theory)), which I would suggest you to start with. But in short, the mutual information between two variables, measures how much a given feature can explain another (target), or more technically, how much information about the target will variable will be obtained by having observed a feature.

This is in fact, the measure that internally dicision trees trained through the [Iterative Dichotomiser 3](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ID3_algorithm) use to decide which feature to set as node in each split, and the subsequent thresholds to set. The only difference between both methods is that one works for discrete targets, and the other for continuous targets.